# How to initiate catchup at Airflow?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm using the Airflow GUI.
I put these in default args:

```
'depends_on_past': False,  
'retries': 3,  
'cathup':True,  
'start_date': datetime(2020,1,1),
```

in DAG args:

```
   default_args=default_args,  
    start_date=datetime(2020,1,1),  
    schedule_interval='12 11 * * *'  
    catchup=True
```

But still, when 11:12 comes, it runs for today, and nothing else. I'd think it starts to backfill from Jan 1 automatically, but it does not. What am I doing wrong, or what must I do to get it triggered by itself?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right, It should start from (2020, 1 , 1). 
Maybe you could set the catchup on airflow.cfg, so it will be the default.

```
 Turn off scheduler catchup by setting this to False.
# Default behavior is unchanged and
# Command Line Backfills still work, but the scheduler
# will not do scheduler catchup if this is False,
# however it can be set on a per DAG basis in the
# DAG definition (catchup)

[scheduler]
catchup_by_default = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set catchup in dag parameter ,like schedule_interval.eg:dag = DAG("test", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="0 11 * * 1",catchup=True)